# How to count distinct a field cumulatively using recursive cte or other method in SQL?

Tags: sql, recursive-query, recursive-cte

Using example below, Day 1 will have 1,3,3 distinct name(s) for A,B,C respectively.
When calculating distinct name(s) for each house on Day 2, data up to Day 2 is used.
When calculating distinct name(s) for each house on Day 3, data up to Day 3 is used.

Can recursive cte be used?

Data:

| Day | House | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | Jack |
| 1 | B | Pop |
| 1 | C | Anna |
| 1 | C | Dew |
| 1 | C | Franco |
| 2 | A | Jon |
| 2 | B | May |
| 2 | C | Anna |
| 3 | A | Jon |
| 3 | B | Ken |
| 3 | C | Dew |
| 3 | C | Dew |

Result:

| Day | House | Distinct names |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 1 |
| 1 | B | 1 |
| 1 | C | 3 |
| 2 | A | 2 (jack and jon) |
| 2 | B | 2 |
| 2 | C | 3 |
| 3 | A | 2 (jack and jon) |
| 3 | B | 3 |
| 3 | C | 3 |

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the need and size of data it'll be hard to give an ideal/optimal solution. Assuming a small dataset needing a quick and dirty way to calculate, just use sub query like this...

```
SELECT p.[Day]
    , p.House
    , (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT([Name]))
        FROM #Bing
        WHERE [Day]<= p.[Day] AND House = p.House) DistinctNames
FROM #Bing p
GROUP BY [Day], House
ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a recursive CTE.  Just mark the first time a name is seen in a house and use a cumulative sum:

```
select day, house,
       sum(sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end)) over (partition by house order by day) as num_unique_names
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by house, name order by day) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by day, house
```

Comment: Turns out that my use case is a little different and use both of Sai Puli's and yours :) upvoted yours

Comment: @jasonlcy91 . . . This should be, by far, the more performant solution.